# Java File I/O problems

Tags: java, io

This is my first time working with file i/o in java, and it's not working. The section of the program where I parse individual lines and output a semicolon delimited line works like a charm when I hardcode a file and display on screen.

Whne I try to write to a file `public static OutputStream...` errors out as an `illegal start to expression`, and I've been unable to get the program to step through an entire directory of files instead of one at a time.

Where I'm not clear: I'm note setting an output filename anywhere...whare am I supposed to do that?  The path variable won't pass. What's the proper format for a path? Can anyone see what I need to debug here?

```
import java.nio.*;
public class FileReadSSCCE
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
     Path startingDir = Paths.get("R:\Data\cs\RoboHelp\CorrLib\Output\Production\WebHelp");
      PrintFiles pf = new PrintFiles();
      Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, pf);
  // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String inputLine;
            String desc = "";
            String docNo = "";
  //Read File Line By Line
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                int testVal=0;
                int stringMax = inputLine.length();
//
                if(inputLine.startsWith("Description"))
                  {desc = inputLine.substring(13,inputLine.length());}
                   else
                   if(inputLine.startsWith("Reference Number"))
                     {docNo = inputLine.substring(20,inputLine.length());}    
            }    
// Print the content on the console
            String outStr1 = (desc + ";" + docNo);
            System.out.print(inputLine + "\n" + outStr1);
            String lineItem = (outStr1);
//    
            try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream
                 (logfile.newOutputStream(CREATE, APPEND)))
                 {
                     out.write(lineItem, 0, lineItem.length);
                 }
                 catch (IOException x)
                 {
                     System.err.println(x);
                 }
                 public static OutputStream newOutputStream() throws IOException
                 {
                       // append to an existing file, create file if it doesn't initially exist
                       out = Files.newOutputStream((Paths.get("c:\javaout.txt"), CREATE, APPEND);
                 }

//Close the input stream
            in.close();
       } 
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           //Catch exception if any
           System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Does the line `Path startingDir = R:\Data\cs\RoboHelp\CorrLib\Output\Production\WebHelp;` really look like this in your code: `"Path startingDir = R:\\Data\\cs\\RoboHelp\\CorrLib\\Output\\Production\\WebHelp;"`

Comment: @GavinCattell the first quote in your comment should come after the `=`.

Comment: @GavinCattell - the path does not have double \\ , just singles...but that's how it appears in ~my~ browser, so something must be parsing funky. That being said, I ~just~ learned about the paths.get method, which is likely the source of my problems. I'll try that and be back if I have issues.

Comment: @dwwilson66 you'll need to use ``\\`` (or `/` will suffice!) instead of ``\`` because ``\`` is the escape character. This means that if you want a string to actually contain a ``\``, you need to escape it: ``\\``. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html#h101

Comment: Aha! Thanks @MДΓΓ БДLL! \\ is good info!

Comment: @ I'm using `import java.nio.*` but `Path startingDir = Paths.get("R:\\Data\\cs\\RoboHelp\\CorrLib\\Output\\Production\\WebHelp");` tells me that it can't find the symbol `Paths`. Does the * in import pull in ALL sub-classes and sub-sub-classes? Or do I need to explicitly code java.nio.files? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
Path startingDir = Paths.get("R:/Data/cs/RoboHelp/CorrLib/Output/Production/WebHelp");
```

?

Also in your code, fstream is not initialised. Have you copied your code logic in the `visitFile` method of your Visitor?

And you define a method within your main method - which is not allowed:

```
        public static OutputStream newOutputStream() throws IOException
        {  
            // append to an existing file, create file if it doesn't initially exist  
            out = Files.newOutputStream(c:, CREATE, APPEND);
        }
```

Comment: Short answer, yes. Long answer...I need to hunt down Paths methods and do some poking around.

Comment: @dwwilson66 the JavaDoc is your friend. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

Comment: @dwwilson66 There are many compile errors in your code - can you try to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: @assylias - Short answer, yes. Long answer...I need to hunt down Paths methods and do some poking around. And having done that, `Path startingDir = Paths.get("R:\Data\cs\RoboHelp\CorrLib\Output\Production\WebHelp");` results in an `illegal escape character` error. Back to the tutorials...

Comment: @dwwilson66 You are using `\ ` instead of `/`

Comment: @assylias - updated my question with a SSCCE - only two fields.

Comment: @assylias - I'll be editing the \ and making sure my curly braces and placed properly so I don't have nested methods. It took me a while to find where I messed THAT one up! :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `Files.newOutputStream(c:, CREATE, APPEND);` you've got a syntax error because of the `c:` part. You have to pass a [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) instance to [`Files.newOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29).

You can obtain such an instance using one of the methods in [`Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html).

Likewise, it appears that you meant to initialize `startingPath` something like this (using a string):

```
Path startingPath = "R:\Data\cs\RoboHelp\CorrLib\Output\Production\WebHelp";
```

but you need to use `Paths` to convert a `String` into a `Path`:

```
Path startingPath = Paths.get("R:\Data\cs\RoboHelp\CorrLib\Output\Production\WebHelp");
```

Answer (score 0):

The path must be in double quotes.

Comment: No, `Files.newOutputStream()` takes a `Path`, not a `String`. -1